# Optimise RANK based query in Create View

Tags: sql, oracle, create-view

I have a view and i used 2 select cases in order to us ethe RANK function.
Is there a way to optimise this and avoid the 2 select clauses and make it one.

The query is as below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "TEMP" (
   "P_LOCAL_POLICY_ID",
   "P_GIRDA_POLICY_ID",
   "C_OE_CONS_UNIT_TITLE",
   "C_ROW_NUMBER",
   "C_LOAD_TIMESTAMP",
   "ERROR_TEXT",
   "RECORD_2_DELETE",
   "ERROR_TIMESTAMP",
   "RANK_NUMBER"
) AS
   SELECT
       p_local_policy_id,
       p_girda_policy_id,
       c_oe_cons_unit_title,
       c_row_number,
       c_load_timestamp,
       err_error_text,
       err_record_2_delete,
       err_load_timestamp,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY
           err_error_text
           ORDER BY
               ROWNUM
       )
   FROM
       (
           SELECT
               po.local_policy_id AS p_local_policy_id,
               po.girda_policy_id AS p_girda_policy_id,
               MAX(cl.oe_cons_unit_title) AS c_oe_cons_unit_title,
               SUM(cl.row_number) AS c_row_number,
               MAX(cl.load_timestamp) AS c_load_timestamp,
               error.error_text AS err_error_text,
               error.record_2_delete AS err_record_2_delete,
               error.load_timestamp AS err_load_timestamp
           FROM
              <condition>
           WHERE
                  <condition>
           GROUP BY
               po.local_policy_id,
               po.girda_policy_id,
               error.error_text,
               error.record_2_delete,
               error.load_timestamp
       );
```

Thanks,
Chithra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two blocks of SELECT list as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEMP AS
SELECT po.local_policy_id AS "P_LOCAL_POLICY_ID",
       po.girda_policy_id AS "P_GIRDA_POLICY_ID",
       MAX(cl.oe_cons_unit_title) AS "C_OE_CONS_UNIT_TITLE",
       SUM(cl.row_number) AS "C_ROW_NUMBER",
       MAX(cl.load_timestamp) AS "C_LOAD_TIMESTAMP",
       error.error_text AS "ERROR_TEXT",
       error.record_2_delete AS "RECORD_2_DELETE",
       error.load_timestamp AS "ERROR_TIMESTAMP",
       RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY err_error_text ORDER BY 1 ) AS "RANK_NUMBER"
  FROM <condition>
 WHERE <condition>
 GROUP BY po.local_policy_id, po.local_region,
          error.error_text, error.record_2_delete, error.load_timestamp
```

- no need to list those column aliases after view name.
- underscore characters might be removed within column names such as
  `"P LOCAL POLICY ID"` instead of `"P_LOCAL_POLICY_ID"` as already
  being quoted

Comment: i can give you the full code, can i attach as a file here?

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: its says too long

Comment: i updated the code in the main section.please check

Comment: @chithra  just replace `ROWNUM` with a constatnt such as `1` within analytic function's ORDER BY Clause. Since it corrupts the GROUPing as a non-aggregated column.

Comment: i tried this , this will become 1 in the rank number column which is wrong

Comment: Determine another ordering column rather than `rownum` , which's generated by DB arbitrarily, since SQL select statements represent unordered sets, and thet column should be in the group by list for your case @chithra

Comment: the ordering column should be unique right, here we don't have unique columns. can we create row number here and then use his column in the group by?

Comment: you can do but if you nest this query as a subquery and grouping by within the outer (main) query, but really need this. Perhaps directly choosing some columns, even all `po.local_policy_id, po.local_region, error.error_text, error.record_2_delete, error.load_timestamp` in the GROUP BY expression might be also put into the ORDER BY clause of the RANK() function considering this combination would have produce uniqueness, am I right ? @chithra